# Hypernym for "team member" and "contributor"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

I work on a web app where the users make forecast of people.

They have to inform for each person with forecast if it's a "TEAM MEMBER" (i. e. the user is the manager of the resource) or a "CONTRIBUTION" (i. e. the user ask the resource from another team).

I don't know how to name this "status" of the people. Do you know any word describing if a person belongs to the team?

Comment: **Membership**: *team* or *external* (or *third-party*, etc)?

Comment: Perhaps  *Contributors* for "team members" and *requesting visitors* for non affiliate, to convey the idea of membership vs partnership.

Comment: Well, the difference is in which manager the individual *reports to*.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that what you are looking for is

> [affiliation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/affiliation): a person’s connection with a political party, religion, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your question partially contains the answer:

member--nonmember

Comment: I think the question is asking what to call this member/non-member status -- that is, what the title of a table column would be above a list of "member/contributor/contributor/member/member..." He already has the words *member* and *contributor*.